# 504 Gateway Time-out - ec2, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

I try to deploy my rails app for AWS EC2 server.

When I access static IP, '504 Gateway Time-out' is shown.

I want to solve this problem, maybe nginx config is wrong.

**environment**

```
rails 6.0
mac OS
aws EC2
```

**Problem**

```
When I access top page, 504 Gateway Time-out is shown.
nginx.log has 'Connection timed out' error
```

**nginx.cofig**

```
events{}
http{
  upstream unicorn{
    server unix:/var/www/rails/blog1/tmp/unicorn.sock;
  }
server{
  listen: 8081;
  server_name IP address;
  
  root /var/www/rails/blog1/public;

  access_log /var/www/rails/blog1/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /var/www/rails/blog1/log/nginx.error.log;

  fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
  client_max_body_size 100m;
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location @unicorn{
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }
 }
}
```

**nginx.log**

```
2020/09/13 21:09:00[error] 19985#0: *101 upstream timed out(110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.52.199.208, server: IP address, request: "GET/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/rails/blog1/tmp/unicorn.sock/favicon.ico", host: "IP address", referrer: "http://IP address/"
```

- IP address is truly EC2 static IP address.

Comment: Have you confirmed that unicorn is running? What do your unicorn logs say?

Comment: You said `s3 static IP address`. Did you mean `ec2 static IP address`?

Comment: Also, if it is ec2 static IP address, does any of the inbound rules in security groups associated to the hosting ec2 instance allow connections to port (8081 in your case) on which nginx is running?

Comment: Thank you for comment,
I checked unicorn is running by `ps aux | grep unicorn`

Comment: Sorry, `ec2 static IP address` is correnct.

As you mentioned, I didn't allow connection for port 8081, only port 80.
So I changed `nginx.config` post 8081 to 80.
`listen: 80;`

Comment: After that, `upstream timed out(110: Connection timed out)`  error still returns.